# SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 2.3.6. Everything works fine on localhost, but when I upload to the server, the custom query in the controller's function throws an error saying "table not found". However, the table does exist.

The database is created in such a manner that I don't have any other way than using a custom query.  Any help appreciated.

**Database Error**

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'kidzo_v3.Children' doesn't exist

**Query:**

```
Insert into Children(Birthdate,Gender,User_id) 
values('1997-11-16','male','14121');
```

Comment: i suspect that kidzo_v3 is not the name of your current database

Comment: All other queries work? Did you change the necessarily values in `databases.php`?

Comment: `custom query in the controller's function` <- why is a custom query in your controller at all. Queries belong in your models.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was I used an upper case name in the custom query :(